# when I delete a VM's endpoint, visit public ip failed

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

This is an windows azure issue:
I have 2 load balance Virtual Machines and run my software on them, when one machine's service is down, I try to delete its public endpoint to make my software can be visited so I will have time to fix the bad one.
Now when I delete it, I can't not visit the public IP for a few minutes, it seems like there has a restart time for deleting an endpoint? 
So who can tell me why?
And If there is 3 load balance machine and I delete one will be better?

(sorry for the bad English, hope you will understand me)

Comment: Seems to me that your loadbalancing architecture/system is not working as it should if you need to manually delete anything.

Comment: The azure load balance is based on network, so if my software's service is down or even the system is down, azure may still visit the bad one. Even I start the machine there still will be a couple minutes for not reaching(The network can be reached but my software will not). So I want to delete it then fix and add to the load balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be deleting the endpoint. For Virtual Machines, traffic on a load-balanced endpoint is sent across your set of Virtual Machines on that endpoint. If you want to remove one of those instances from the traffic flow, you need to set up a custom health probe. Aside from general failures (like your Virtual Machine rebooting or its hardware having issues), Windows Azure won't know if your individual Virtual Machine is healthy or not. With a custom probe handler, the Virtual Machine simply return a 200 when healthy, and non-200 when it wants to be removed from the load balancer (until checked again).

See [this MSDN reference article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj151530.aspx) for details around custom probes for load-balanced endpoints. Also: Michael Washam wrote a [post](http://michaelwasham.com/2012/06/08/understanding-windows-azure-virtual-machines/) that gives a nice overview of Virtual Machines (including custom probes). See his [additional post](http://michaelwasham.com/2012/06/08/automating-windows-azure-virtual-machines-with-powershell/) to see how to configure custom probes through PowerShell.